# How to check if string contain alphabetic characters or alphabetic characters and numbers?

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I want to test STR contain alphabetic as (a-z) (A-Z) or alphabetic with numbers

meanwhile I have this

```
[[ "$STR"  =~ [a-zA-Z0-9] ]] && echo "contain alphanumerics"
```

but this works even STR have only numbers

while we want to print only if STR is contain alphabetic or alphabetic & numbers"

example

will print on the following case

```
gstfg523
HGFER34
JNF
GFGTVT
83bfF
```

will not print on

```
2424
4356
632
@65$
&%^$
82472243(*
```

Comment: alphanumeric *is* letters and numbers.  If your string has to check both, check for letters and then check for numbers (or reverse order).

Comment: ok my target is to check alphanomeic but it will not print if str is only numbers

Comment: So, `$STR` must be fully alphanumeric (nothing but letters and numbers), and not completely made of numbers (at least one letter)?

Comment: @jango, is your string always comprised of multiline text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the examples, I think you want to check that `$STR` is

- fully alphanumeric (nothing but letters and numbers), *and*
- not completely made of numbers (there is least one letter)?

Implementing those conditions:

```
[[ "$STR" =~ ^[[:alnum:]]*$ ]] && [[ ! "$STR" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && echo ok
```

This will also accept the empty string. To change that, use `+` instead of `*` in the first pattern.

Tests:

```
$ for STR in "" . .x .9 x x9 9 ; do 
    echo -en "$STR\t"; 
    [[ "$STR" =~ ^[[:alnum:]]*$ ]] && [[ ! "$STR" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && echo ok || echo not ok ; 
  done 
        ok
.       not ok
.x      not ok
.9      not ok
x       ok
x9      ok
9       not ok
```

Answer (score 4):

For alnums with at least one alpha, that would be:

```
[[ $STR =~ ^[[:alnum:]]*[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*$ ]]
```

(note that contrary to [@ilkkachu's answer](/a/416120), that also excludes the empty string).

Or POSIXly:

```
valid() case $1 in
  (*[![:alnum:]]*) false;;
  (*[[:alpha:]]*) true;;
  (*) false;;
esac

valid "$STR" || printf >&2 '"%s" is not valid\n' "$STR"
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is alphanumeric and not only numbers:

```
[[ "$STR"  =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ ]] && [[ ! "$STR"  =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo …
```

Comment: why it print also in case - STR=Jkk@@

Comment: can you update the answer - if we want only alphabet or  alphabet  with numbers?

Comment: @jango Answer updated.